# Php mssql connection problem in Wordpress

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress

Trying to make a form that'll query a value on an SQL database. That code written originally in c# / .net. Now, I'm trying to make that page on WordPress and I'm trying to use a PHP snippet plugin because I couldn't achieve it to be done with WordPress plugins.  But I couldn't achieve that. I stuck on the connection part.

```
<add name="MTKdatabase" connectionString="data source=11.11.11.11,4550;initial catalog=CATALOG;user id=user;password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Php version:

```
<?php

$serverName = "11.11.11.11, 4550";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"CATALOG", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"pass");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

Any advice for making a query page like that would be appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: With error reporting completely turned on, what error message are you getting?

Comment: The error is : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server support is not enabled by default, you will need to add and enable that extension. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php, https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Now there is another error message:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) )
I don't how to install that driver...

Comment: In the ODBC driver section of that page, first paragraph, there's a link to download it

Comment: Yes, there is, but where I can't install it. My hosting won't allow me to do that on cPanel... There are extensions on cPanel, I enabled it. But still, I get the error...

Comment: Trying enabling the ODBC extension, too

Comment: Thanks for helping, did that too, nothing changed... I think there is an another problem...

Comment: We host many of our sites on cPanel controlled servers, too, but this is at the limit of my experience. I'd recommend contacting your host to see if they have a resolution. I can tell you that it might be a bit of a battle. You need to get PHP and MSSQL to play together, and you need your OS and MSSL to play together, too. And then there's the versions of components.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219575/discussion-between-anixrud-and-chris-haas).